# Get checkins of friends of friends within given radius and lat/long

Tags: api, facebook-checkins

I have a requirement wherein i want to show strangers in a given location and within 1000 meters of radius. So for strangers i feel the only way is to show my friends' friends. As they can be considered as strangers for me.

If i call "**graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin&access_token=...**" i get check-ins of my friends and check-ins where my friends were tagged in. I cannot rely on this call to display strangers.

Can anyone give me valid suggestions? Or is it simply not possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible; the API will only let you access information which is

1. Completely public
2. Belongs to the user of your app which has given you permission to access it
3. Belongs to a friend of the user who has given you permission, assuming those friends' settings allow it